# Tech help with story: Will my radio signal be blocked by a mountain?

Tags: rf, signal, radio, ham-radio

Hoping I can get some help with a technology question for my novel.

My protagonist is being pursued, and they have put a tracker in his arm he cannot remove, lest it blow up and kill him. Pretty standard stuff. It's the future, so maybe the tracker is more sophisticated, but I assume in the end it's still some sort of radio signal. The bad guy has the receiver.

At some point, hero goes to a secret place inside a mountain. He's deep in the caverns, and high up.

Will being inside that mountain block the receiver from knowing where he is?

This is not a hard scifi book, so the details aren't that important. I'm just needed to understand the basics. Think of the tech of Star Wars which is very loose.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is off topic as it is not related to electronic design. But yes, mountains can block radio signals.

Comment: I think there is a world building stack exchange. This might be more suited there, maybe?

Comment: I posted it there, they said it wasn't worldbuilding. :( Feels like safe to say it's blocked.

Comment: @MajorTom - It looks like [your question on Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/152632/will-my-futuristic-homing-tracker-signal-be-lost-inside-a-mountain) is still open.

Comment: Being serious here; salt water is fine attenuator of RF. So wrap the limb in a wet salty towel, then wrap the ensemble in aluminum foil.

Comment: This should be on-topic on Worldbuilding, but definitely not here. You would have to ask about a specific, existing radio technology (frequency band at least), or you would have to ask about the physics behind radio transmission. "They said it wasn't worldbuilding" Ignore random comments like that until your question is actually put on hold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how the tracker works, I suppose. If it uses GPS and/or cell phone networks, it would probably not work. If it warps the space-time continuum and generates a micro-wormhole that uses a detector in a parallel universe, I don't see how a simple mountain would stop it. It's your story! Saying "Star Wars tech" is not constraining the problem at all, since that allows for faster-than-light travel and use of the Force.

You could always just say something about unusual iron deposits distorting the magnetic field or acting as a partial Faraday cage, if you want a somewhat plausible explanation for why the super-advanced tech that works almost everywhere doesn't work in this *particular* mountain.

Comment: Just being deep inside a mountain is enough to block radio waves from all but the most specialized radios.  If it's a near-future kinda thing, you're probably OK.  If it's Star **Trek** technology, then you're OK too -- signals are known to not make it through kilometers of rock in that universe.

Comment: It IS near future - so maybe the Star Wars comment threw you all off. Negative to the whole wormhole thing. I think the most future thing about it is that it has a power source self contained to send a decent signal. That's all. This really helps.